# generating uisegmentedcontrol buttons with a loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, for-loop, uisegmentedcontrol

i am trying to generate sets of segmented control buttons from a loop if given an initial value.

so if the value is 3
i need the loop to generate 3 sets of segmented buttons below each other

this is what i have so far after unsuccessfully trying to adapt codes from tutorials.

```
    var numberOfVillains = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    var buttonY: CGFloat = 20  // our Starting Offset, could be 0
    for number in numberOfVillains {
        let segmentController = UISegmentedControl()
        //let villainButton = UISegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 50, height: 30)){
        buttonY = buttonY + 50  // we are going to space these UIButtons 50px apart
        segmentController.frame = CGRect(x:100, y:200, width: 200,height:  30)
        //segment frame size
        segmentController.insertSegment(withTitle: "1", at: 0, animated: true)
        //inserting new segment at index 0
         segmentController.insertSegment(withTitle: "2", at: 1, animated: true)
        //inserting new segment at index 1
         segmentController.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        //setting the background color of the segment controller
         segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        //setting the segment which is initially selected
         segmentController.addTarget(self, action: "segment:", for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        //calling the selector method
        self.view.addSubview(segmentController)
        //adding the view as subview of the segment comntroller w.r.t. main view controller
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every one of your segmented controller has the same frame, so they stack over each other. You have to use `buttonY` in :

```
segmentController.frame = CGRect(x:100, y:buttonY, width: 200,height:  30)
```

I think that you will see a difference

Comment: spot on, thank you for that. now i just need to figure out why the app crashes when i click on the buttons that were generated :)

Comment: apparently you don't specify a delegate for these SC, you should put on and set the delegate methods. But I don't see why it would crash if you have not set them ...